# Serializer design? When do I need a new serializer?

Tags: serialization, django-rest-framework

In DRF I often come across the question of weather or not I should create a custom serializer for a specific view. There is always that quest of figuring out if existing serializers can be modified to do what I want.

**Example:**

```
class ProductReviewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    product_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductReview
        fields = (
            'uuid',
            'review_score',
            'user',
            'product',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'uuid',
        )

    def get_product_name(self, obj):
        something ...
```

I am using this serializer for creating new instances of `ProductReview`. Furthermore, I want to use this serializer to update instances of `ProductReview` as well. For this the serializer should validate data from an API endpoint that omits a lot of the fields, e. g. the DRF API only receives the JSON `{review_score: 2)`. For the given example I can't get the serializer to be valid unless, I declare a bunch of fields as `read_only` which in turn does not work for creating new instances.

A serializer for editing ProductReviews that accepts the data (`{review_score: ...}`) from above would look something like this:

```
class ProductReviewEditSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductReview
        fields = (
            'review_score',
        )
```

**I feel I am creating some dumb design flaws here. But can you point me in the direction of a better solution?**

Is creating a buch of individual serializers the way to go? My gut feeling tells me, that every Model should just have one serializer ...

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is  a very good question. I am sharing my point of view when we should use serializer. It will be great to read out other people thoughts on this.

#### Why we need Serializer

1. Most important reason is that we don't trust user input always as perfect. There may some malicious intend to do harm in system. So we should always verify as perfect way as possible to validate user data before do any change to our model/system.
2. We want our response in a well established format. It may require to add couple of logical operation beside normal DB query response.

#### Can a single serializer do all possible jobs

I strongly believe it is possible for most of the cases. Still there are some cases where it is not possible. I found `DRF-ModelSerializer` is very power for this job and very well organized too. If your model defination are properly organized. If any additional get response required we can always use `SerializerMethodField` for that job.

#### Possible solution for your problem

I have an intention that you are not passing model-instance whom you want to update with your request data. For partial updating with serialize we should do something like this

```
serializer = ProductReviewSerializer(product_review_model_instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
```